# Suspension of a homology 3 sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M^3$ be a homology sphere: a connected closed 3-manifold  with the same homology groups as $S^3$. Calculate the first fundamental group and homology groups of the suspension $\Sigma M$. Use this to show that the suspension is homotopy-equivalent to $S^4$.

**My Thought** 
I have shown that the fundamental group of the suspension is trivial and it has the same homology groups as $S^4$ but have trouble with proving it is homotopy equivalent to $S^4$. I tried to use the classification of homotopy types of four manifolds, as stated in this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-manifold. However, it requires that $\Sigma M$ is a manifold, which is not clear to me.

Is it true that $\Sigma M$ is indeed a manifold in this case? If not, how to prove they are homotopy equivalent?

Comment: Are you familiar with the homology Whitehead theorem?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Yes, but how can I construct a map from the suspension space to 4 sphere which induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups ?

Comment: Use the Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: @VincentBoelens is correct that you can use Hurweicz theorem, but in this specific case you can use the fact that all orientable manifolds have a degree 1 map to the sphere, given by collapsing everything outside a ball.

Comment: @ConnorMalin But we don't know whether or not the suspension space is a manifold in this case.

Comment: But you know that $M$ is (and by the way $\Sigma M$ is a manifold, if and only if, $M$ is $S^n$).

Comment: So firstly construct a degree 1 map from $M$ to $S^3$ and then it induces a map from the suspension space to $S^4$, which is a homotopy equivalence by Whitehead theorem?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Where can I find a reference on your second statement about $\Sigma M$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784962/easier-proof-about-suspension-of-a-manifold?rq=1