# What is the dimension of the suspension of $\mathbb{R}P^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The suspension $SX$ of a topological space $X$ is defined as follows:
$${\displaystyle S(X)=(X\times I)/\{(x_{1},0)\sim (x_{2},0){\mbox{ and }}(x_{1},1)\sim (x_{2},1){\mbox{ for all }}x_{1},x_{2}\in X\}}.$$

My question is that: what is the dimension of $S(\mathbb{R}P^2)$, the suspension of real projective plane?

Comment: There are various ways to define dimension. Your question is not well-defined.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжевiswithUkraine By dimension here I mean dimension of a polyhedron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension of the suspension is equal to the dimensions of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ plus $1$, so $3$. This is usually the case with 'nice' spaces - taking the suspension increases the dimension by $1$.

In fact, in terms of homology, taking the suspension "shifts" all of the (reduced) homology groups up by one dimension.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct to talk about the dimension of a suspension because it is not a manifold in our example. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784962/easier-proof-about-suspension-of-a-manifold)